# What is the difference between these 2 expression using Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I'm actually reading some guide to use Prometheus and I'm not sure about something.

```
name=~".+" --> take all the names
```

But then when I have read https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/operators/ I just saw:

```
+ (addition)
- (subtraction)
* (multiplication)
/ (division)
% (modulo)
^ (power/exponentiation)
```

So I don't understand how to first query can select all `name` despite the operator are for addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're two different parts of the langauge, `=~` is a label selector used within curly braces. The others are the usual arithmetic operators.

Comment: Ok maybe it's the time for me to go in weekend ^^ thank your for the help